# wire:click does not call the function from component

Tags: laravel-livewire

I'm trying to implement the Like functionality on a post. I have the LikeButton component, which I am adding in "single-post" view as follows:

```
@extends("front.layouts.pages-layout")
@section("pageTitle", isset($pageTitle) ? $pageTitle : "SDblog")
@section("content")
  <div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
              <article>
                  <img loading="lazy" decoding="async" src="/storage/images/post_images/{{$post->post_image}}" alt="{{$post->post_title}} image" class="w-100">
                  <ul class="post-meta mb-2 mt-4">
                      <li>
                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" style="margin-right:5px;margin-top:-4px" class="text-dark" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                              <path d="M5.5 10.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 10h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"></path>
                              <path d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM2 2a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v11a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V3a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2z"></path>
                              <path d="M2.5 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V4z"></path>
                          </svg> <span>{{dateFormatter($post->created_at)}}</span>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                  <h1 class="my-3">{{$post->post_title}}</h1>
                  <ul class="post-meta mb-4">
                      @if($post->subcategory != null)
                          <li>
                              <a href="{{route("categoryPosts",$post->subcategory->slug)}}">{{$post->subcategory->subcategory_name}}</a>
                          </li>
                      @endif
                  </ul>
                  <div class="content text-left">
                      <p>
                          {!! $post->post_content !!}
                      </p>

                  </div>
                  @if($post->post_tags)
                      <div class="tags-container mt-4">

                          <ul class="post-meta">
                              @foreach($tags = explode(",",$post->post_tags) as $tag)
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="{{route("tagPosts",$tag)}}">#{{$tag}}</a>
                                  </li>
                              @endforeach                        
                         </ul>

                      </div>
                  @endif
              </article>
              @if(count($relatedPosts) > 0)
                  <div class="widget-list mt-4">
                      <h2 class="mb-2">S-ar putea sa te intereseze si : </h2>
                      @foreach($relatedPosts as $item)
                          <a class="media align-items-center" href="{{route("readPost",$item->post_slug)}}">
                              <img loading="lazy" decoding="async" src="/storage/images/post_images/{{$item->post_image}}" alt="{{$item->post_title}} image" class="w-100">
                              <div class="media-body ml-3">
                                  <h3 style="margin-top:-5px">{{$item->post_title}}</h3>
                                  <p class="mb-0 small">{{Str::ucfirst(words($item->post_content,20))}}</p>
                              </div>
                          </a>
                      @endforeach
                  </div>
              @endif
              <div class="mt-5">
                  @if(Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->type == 3 || Auth::user()->type == 2))

     <livewire:like-button :key="$post->id" :post="$post"/>
   
                  @else
                      <h2>
                          <a href="{{route("user.login")}}">Autentifica-te</a> pentru a lasa un comentariu
                      </h2>
                  @endif
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="widget-blocks">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                          <div class="widget">
                              <div class="widget-body">
                                  <img loading="lazy" decoding="async" src="{{$post->author->picture}}" alt="About Me" class="w-50  d-block">
                                  <h2 class="widget-title my-3">{{$post->author->name}}</h2>
                                  <p class="mb-3 pb-2">{{Str::ucfirst(words($post->author->biography,20))}}</p> <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Know
                                      More</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      @if(displayRandomRecomandedPost())
                          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
                              <div class="widget">
                                  <h2 class="section-title mb-3">Recomandari</h2>
                                  <div class="widget-body">
                                      <div class="widget-list">
                                          @foreach(displayRandomRecomandedPost() as $recomandedPost)
                                              <a class="media align-items-center" href="{{route("readPost",$recomandedPost->post_slug)}}">
                                                  <img loading="lazy" decoding="async" src="/storage/images/post_images/{{$recomandedPost->post_image}}"
                                                       alt="Post Thumbnail" class="w-100">
                                                  <div class="media-body ml-3">
                                                      <h3 style="margin-top:-5px">{{$recomandedPost->post_title}}</h3>
                                                      <p class="mb-0 small">
                                                          {!! Str::ucfirst(words($recomandedPost->post_content,5)) !!}
                                                      </p>
                                                  </div>
                                              </a>
                                          @endforeach
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      @endif
                      <x-categories-list/>
                      <x-tags-list/>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

This is my component blade file :

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="toggleLike()">
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        <span>Like</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

And here is my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;

class LikeButton extends Component
{
    public Post $post;

    public function toggleLike(){
        dd("ceva");
    }
    public function mount(Post $post){
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.like-button');
    }
   
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the button, it doesn't call the function (in my code, I have a simple dd() as a test, but that doesn't change the situation. Does anyone know how I could avoid this ?

I tried to "change" the button in a livewire component(remember that singe-post.blade.php is a regular blade, not a livewire component) and there it worked. I guess that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

This all looks good to me. Usually when I call a function like this I would declare it like this:

```
<button wire:click="toggleLike">
```

Sometimes also when doing the die and dump function the DD is triggered but not displayed as it's a http request which returns a 200 on the livewire event. A better way to "test" something like this (in my opinion) is to map a variable.

try this:

```
<div>
    @json($toggle)
    <button wire:click="toggleLike">
        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        <span>Like</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Then set a bool in your livewire component:

```
public Post $post;
public $toggle = 0;

public function toggleLike(){
    $this->toggle = !$this->toggle;
}
```

You should see the toggle change from false to true on click. If it's still not working then double check your livewire includes...

Best of luck!

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. I even turned "single-page.blade.php" into a separate component, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: ok then we back it up. inspect your web page, is the livewire JS / CSS included?

Comment: Also I had an error in my component. $this->toggle = !$this->toggle; was $toggle = !$toggle;